Why does my code assign 0.0000000 to my variables before the user has a chance to input them?
This is my code.
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Write a C program that accepts two integers from the user then outputs the sum, difference, product,        and division of the two integers.
*/

float main()
{
    float x, y; //defining input variables and the output/answer

    printf("Input the first number: %f", x); //user inputs 1st number
    scanf("%f", &x);

    printf("Input the second number: %f", y); //user inputs 2nd number
    scanf("%f", &y);
    printf("\n");

//math
    float sum = x + y;
    float diff = x - y;
    float product = x * y;
    float div = x / y;

//outputting the math
    printf("The sum is: %.2f\n", sum);
    printf("The difference is: %.2f\n", diff);
    printf("The product is: %.2f\n", product);
    printf("The division is: %.2f\n", div);

    return 0.0;
}

Yes, I do want it to be float variables and not int so that it can calculate division more accurately. Doing so will avoid it outputting 2/3 = 0.

float main() is quite unusual.  Who suggested that?`

printf("Input the first number: %f", x); is very strange; why are you printing it before being input, and why are you bothered by whatever value comes out - depending on the compiler, flags, or even day of the week, the output could be 0.000, 42.424242e42, or just a horrendous crash.

"warning: 'x' is used uninitialized". Your code doesn't assign any values to x and y before the user input. There are a couple of reasons why they may start out appearing that way, but that is not guaranteed and you must not rely on it. You really shouldn't be attempting to use their values before they are properly established.

This question is similar to: What should happen when printing an uninitialized variable?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
